# Datatable Search return Sql Excelption

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

when the table loads for the first time it loads normally but if I type something in the search box I get an SQL Exception this is my code:

```
public function getProducts(Request $request)
{

    $data = Product::
            select(['products.id',
                    'products.name',
                    'products.price',
                    'products.cost',
                    'products.is_group as pack',
                    'products.created_at',
                     DB::raw("(select path from product_images where product_id =products.id and CASE WHEN path IS NULL THEN  'productImages/no-image.png' else path  END) as path")
            ]);
    if ($request->wirehouse)
    { 
        $wirehouse = $request->wirehouse;
        $data->selectRaw(DB::raw('(select if(sum(stocks.qte) > 0 , sum(stocks.qte) , 0) from stocks
                                   where stocks.product_id = products.id and
                                   stocks.wirehouse_id = ' . $wirehouse . ')
                                   - (select if(sum(stocks.qte) > 0 , sum(stocks.qte) , 0)
                                   from stocks where stocks.product_id = products.id and stocks.stock_id
                                   in (select stocks.id from stocks where stocks.product_id = products.id
                                   and stocks.wirehouse_id = ' . $wirehouse . ') ) as total_stock ,
                                   (select if(sum(items.quantity) > 0 , sum(items.quantity) , 0) from orders,
                                   items where orders.id = items.order_id and items.product_id = products.id
                                   and (orders.status in (4,5,6,9,11) or (orders.status = 8 and orders.recover = 0))
                                   and items.wirehouse_id = ' . $wirehouse . ') as out_stock'));
        $data->havingRaw('total_stock - out_stock != 0');
  
    }
    else
    {
        $data->selectRaw(DB::raw('(select if(sum(stocks.qte) > 0 , sum(stocks.qte) , 0) from stocks where stocks.product_id = products.id and stocks.stock_id = 0  and stocks.confirm = 1) as total_stock '));

        $data->selectRaw(DB::raw('(select if(sum(items.quantity) > 0 , sum(items.quantity) , 0) from orders,
                                   items where orders.id = items.order_id and items.product_id = products.id
                                   and (orders.status in (4,5,6,9,11) or (orders.status = 8 and 
                                   orders.recover = 0))) as out_stock'));                           
                                 
        $data->selectRaw(DB::raw('(select ifnull( sum(items.quantity*groups.qte) , 0) from orders
                                   JOIN items on items.order_id=orders.id join `groups` on
                                   groups.main = items.product_id where orders.id = items.order_id 
                                   and groups.product_id=products.id and (orders.status in (4,5,6,9,11) or
                                   (orders.status = 8 and orders.recover = 0))) as grp '));
    }
    $data->orderBy(DB::raw('total_stock - out_stock + grp') , "Desc");

    return DataTables::of($data)->make(true);
}
```

and this is the Exception I get when I search:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`product_id = products`.`id and stocks`.`stock_id = 0  and' at line 12

I use Laravel 8 and MySQL 8.0.21

Comment: It seems to be adding ticks on your raw statements, but I'm not sure why. You don't need raw on both the select and inside the select, though. Just one will do

Comment: @aynber can you please give me an example ?

Comment: Well the error says `'.\`product_id = products\`.\`id and stocks\`.\`stock_id = 0  and` Note that the backticks `\`` are not correctly placed. Thats the error, but that does not appear to be what you are showing us in the code. **Are you sure this is the code where the error is coming from**

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I am sure  and I think that the filtring is happening inside the DataTables function

Comment: `selectRaw(DB::raw(` You're passing in raw twice. Either use just `selectRaw(` or `select(DB::raw(`. It probably doesn't make a difference, query-wise, but it does avoid passing it in as raw twice.

Comment: @aynber thanks for your comment , i did what you said but still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers, I have solved my issue by Filtring Records Manually by changing `DataTables::of($data)->make(true);` to :

```
DataTables::eloquent($data)
        ->filter(function ($query) {
            $num=is_numeric(request()->search['value']);
            if (request()->search['value']!=null && !$num) {
                $query->where('products.name','like', "%" . request()->search['value'] . "%");
            }else {
                $query->where('products.price','like', "%" . request()->search['value'] . "%");
                $query->Orwhere('products.cost','like', "%" . request()->search['value'] . "%");
            }
        }, false)
        ->toJson();
```